# checked versus default pseudo classes

Tags: css

What is the difference `checked` and `default` pseudo-class cause they look similar? I'm confused. Please someone explain between two property diff.

```css
* {
  border: none;
}

:checked {
  outline: 3px solid orange;
}

:default {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
<!-- While :default pseudo-class defined last in CSS file this style win, when :checked pseudo-class defined in CSS file this last style win -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`:default` is not necessary to use. It defines a default value. `:checked` only applies when the element is checked. The issue is, that you use `:default` last which also overwrites the previous `:checked` selector. If you swap them, it will work:

```css
* {
  border: none;
}

:default {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
}

:checked {
  outline: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
<!-- While :default pseudo-class defined last in CSS file this style win, when :checked pseudo-class defined in CSS file this last style win -->
```

Answer (score 0):

ı found what is the diffrence `:checked` and `:default` pseudo class.

if form element default selected on web page `:default` psuedo class works. when form element checked in this situation `:checked` psuedo class works.

There is matter here when these pseudo classes both use in web page `:checked` is must be come first then `:default` because checked form element matched both pseudo class in this situation last written class wins.

```css
/* when form element checked this style works. */
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  outline: 3px solid green;
}
/* works on  default selected radio button  */
input[type="radio"]:default {
  outline: 3px solid orange;
}

input {
  border: none;
}

fieldset {
  width: fit-content;
}

fieldset,
input {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
   <fieldset>
        <legend>:default examples</legend>
        <label for=""><input type="radio" checked="checked">Default selected radio button</label>
        <label for=""><input type="radio">Not selected radio button but when selected :checked psuedo class
            works</label>
    </fieldset>
```